# Ajax just applies on last row in while statement

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, setinterval

I am doing this animation program where i am frequently updating data in browser with an ajax script. Simplyfied the code a bit so you will understand what I want to do. To start with I have ID's for each item in the animation in an **array** which I use a while statement for. In the **while** I save the value to javascript variable and uses it in ajax. The ajax got an **timed interval** becuase of the updating.

Later on when I am trying to output the variables in Ajax, only the last value of the array will be handled by Ajax, but I want them all.

The output is shown as blue quadratic containers and while hovering over a square the id (trid) of my item will show up.

I am not so good at this so I am very greatful for answers :)

Here is code:

```
<?php   

$id1 = 0;       

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){        

    $id1 = $id1 + 1;    // + 1 for each row in array
    $TR_ID = $rows['trid']; // Ex Py 12938
?>

<div> 
    <script>                              
        var jid = '<?php echo $id1; ?>'; // + 1 for each row in array                   
        var id = '<?php echo $TR_ID; ?>';       // Contains id's like PY12938                       
    </script>
</div>

<!-- Container where output is shown -->            
<div class="hover" id="container" style="width:50px; height:50px; position:relative; background-color:blue;"> 

    <script>
        document.getElementById('container').id = id;
    </script>

    <span id="id_<?php echo $id1; ?>" style="position:absolute;"> <!--ID = id_xxxxx -->

    </span>

</div>


<script>

    setInterval("ajaxCall()",5000);
    function ajaxCall() 
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",       
            url: 'api.php',          
            data:  {id: id}, 
            dataType: 'json',               
            success: function(data)  
            {   
                var trid = data[0].trid; // Ex PY12938

                var hover = (trid); // Same 
                document.getElementById("id_<?php echo $id1 ?>").innerHTML = hover; // Sending ex PY12938 to div which is named "id_PY12938".

            }  
        });
    };  

</script>

<?php
}   
?>
```

Here is php for ajax (UPDATED):

```
<?php 
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";

  $databaseName = "mydb";
  $tableName = "table1";
  $tableName2 = "table2";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);



$ID = @$_POST['id'];
$sqlCompareId = "(table1.trid = '".$ID."' AND table1.trid = table2.trid)";

$data = ("select * from table1, table2 where $sqlCompareId"); 

$result = mysql_query($data);
$dataArray = array();

while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $dataArray[] = $array;
} 

echo json_encode($dataArray);


?>
```

If we say my output now is 4 square divs below each other with id 1,2,3,4. Only the div with id=4 will show its **trid** with hover.

Maybe I cant run mulitple ajax in same while?

Ask if you don't understand me!
Thanks!

Comment: Could you include some outputted html/js code for us to look at please?

Comment: What exactly do you need? :) I updated with the php file i have for ajax. The rest of my html is pretty much not relevant. I have animation code which is based on the id which is outputted in the squares in code. @TomHorwood

Comment: what is the value of `id` in `ajaxCall` that u sent check that id is it same every-time or changes

Comment: Well everything is in the while(row) so the id changes for each row. I am not pretty sure this is possible, pretty new to this. The Ajax function seems to only work for the last row. Which seems pretty logic, but don't know how to do it in another way. If I put my ajax outside the row i need to save each id for itself and it will give me alot of code. Need to make it so general as possible @BluAngel

Comment: @AlexGoransson i think it will be best if you create `jsFiddle` for it

Answer (score 0):

```
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){

//loop start.....
?>
    <script>
<?   
        setInterval("ajaxCall(<?php echo $id1 ?>)",5000);
<?
} // loop end here
?>
        function ajaxCall(idval) 
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",       
                url: 'api.php',          
                data:  {id: id}, 
                dataType: 'json',               
                success: function(data)  
                {   
                    var trid = data[0].trid; // Ex PY12938

                    var hover = (trid); // Same 
                    document.getElementById("id_"+idval).innerHTML = hover; // Sending ex PY12938 to div which is named "id_PY12938".

                }  
            });
        };  

    </script>
```

This code will help u.

instead of repeatedly defining ajax function just call ajax method with repeated times.